# Privatemsg rule problem

Tags: rules, privatemsg

With [Privatemsg](https://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) and [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) modules, I want to create a rule :

Anyone create a node, a special role user recept accepted a privatemsg.

But when I create the rule, in the actions, meet a problem:

The "Data selector" in RECIPIENT, I can't find the role.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean: "special role user recept accepted a privatemsg."  Could you clarify?

Comment: It means users who has role A, can accept a privatemsg.

Answer (score 1):

The *Recipient* in the Privatemsg rules integration does not provide a user object, because the recipient could be a user or a role.  (There is a Privatemsg function for sending messages to roles, not just individual users.)

So, this is a limitation of the Privatemsg rules integration.  If you want to do this, you will have to add that functionality to the module yourself.